# Mojolicious autostart/init() subroutine

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Is there a method/feature to write auto-start subroutine/method for all available Mojolicious routes ?

Maybe an automatic helper, but I don't know how to do it yet.

I think this is useful especially to initialize database connection $self->{dbh} for nearly every available routes, ... so I can write like this:

```
helper DB => sub { state $dbh = Database->new };

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    //$self->{dbh}  // is automatically initialized & shared
};

get '/another_route' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    //$self->{dbh}  // also initialized & shared

};
```

instead of:

```
get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{dbh} = init_db();
};

get '/another_route' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{dbh} = init_db();
};
```

P.S: I'm using Mojolicious:Lite, Perl 5.16, SQLite3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, `helper` does almost exactly what you want, but you shouldn't be using the object's hash. Here is how you would use your code:

```
helper db => sub { state $dbh = Database->new };

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->db->do_somthing();
};

get '/another_route' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $dbh = $self->db;
    ...
};
```

`helper` methods are available for use by all controllers, templates and the main app.

Comment: yes, you're right, but do you know how to directly access $self->{dbh} instead of $self->DB->{dbh} on Mojolicious helper ?
or maybe there's no interface exist yet ?

Comment: First of all, accessing instance data directly is frowned upon in OOP. Perl (and most scripting languages) cannot enforce private data, but you should respect it by design. Second, the invocant to the route callbacks is a new instance of Mojolicious::Controller, so no, you cannot pre-populate that instance data even if you wanted to. By using `state` in the helper, you make a persistent instance of your database connection (see also DBIx::Connector) and calling the method `db` in my example will fetch that instance.